# what does command c#define mean in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, preprocessor-directive

I am new in FORTRAN trying to understand some code:

```
c#define _USE_MPI_

#ifndef _NX_
```

Is this fortran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [pre-processor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) flags, not valid Fortran. You would need to enable a pre-processor like `cpp` (`gfortran`) or `fpp` (`ifort`).

With `#define` you can define a variable or [a macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros). Using [`#ifdef` and `#ifndef`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html#Ifdef) you can perform checks on those variables.

I assume these directives are present in your code to enable different routines or statements when compiled with and without MPI - not unlike an `if`-statement at compile-time. This is usually done to be able to run the code in a purely serial mode as well.

The `c` before the pre-processor directive is probably to comment it out (which would be FORTRAN syntax), to prevent it from being interpreted by the pre-processor.

Comment: Hello In Fortran code both ! & c are used. Is c (e.g. c#define) like ! for commenting?

Comment: yes, a `c` in the first column makes the line a comment for fixed-form FORTRAN (like `!`).